# Rescaling images in Docassemble docx template

Tags: jinja2, docassemble, docxtpl

Usually, like described [here](https://docassemble.org/docs/fields.html#file), images uploaded into DocAssemble (DA) can be put into the template with the corresponding Jinja2 tag defined in the DA YAML file like:

```
question: |
  Please upload a picture of yourself.
fields:
  - Picture: user_picture
    datatype: file
```

If `{{ user_picture }}` is written somewhere in the docx template, the image will be put there. (see [doc](https://docassemble.org/docs/documents.html#docx%20template%20file))

But how can I influence the size of the image in the later docx file?

There are no Jinja2 filters that are applicable. The only solution I found was that DocAssemble uses the package [docxtpl](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and in the documentation there is a method for replacing docx images:

```
tpl.replace_pic('dummy_header_pic.jpg','header_pic_i_want.jpg')
```

But I don't find the right way to call this method from within the DA YAML file.
What is best practice to put images with a definded width and height into a docx template with DocAssemble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write `{{ user_picture.show(width="2in") }}`. For more information about the `.show()` method, see the [documentation](https://docassemble.org/docs/objects.html#DAFile) for `DAFile`. This also works in the context of displaying images on the screen.